# Copying modified files while maintaining folder structure

Tags: svn, copy, directory-structure

I'm working with a bunch of html files and image files in a folder structure that has many sub, sub-sub, sub-sub-sub, etc folders.

I'm working on a series of files that are dispersed throughout this structure and need to provide those files to my client.

However, if I just save the files I've worked on in a zipped file - the folder structure is destroyed (and links are broken). Is there a way to save a certain set of files (maybe changed ones as determined by Beyond Compare) and maintain the original folder structure?

Things I've considered and have been nixed by me or the client:

- Subversion
- Git
- Shared network location
- flat list of files that then need to be placed in the exact same place as before

Additionally, I'm not knowledgeable in scripting language - I know HTML and CSS.

I've looked in to xcopy and robocopy but I think both are either too old/unsupported AND I have no idea how to use them.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a pretty convoluted workflow. Do you and your client have the same files? How do you make sure you have the same files exactly so you can work on them?

Well you could look at using a patch file (which is a file describing changes in a set of files) but that would create it's own set of problems down the line. You can easily create a patch file if you had all your files in a source control system such as subversion and then put your changes in your working copy. But your client applying the patch file could prove tricky.

I would suggest you use a distributed source control system like git. It would involve a bit of learning curve for you and your client but it will save you hours of frustration in the long run.